# How to get two files having max difference among a series of files

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a sequence of .csv files, which contain columnar (5 columns) data separated by a white space. Filenames are in this format 'yyyymmdd.csv'. File format for example as given below:

content of  20161201.csv

```
key value more columns (this line (header) is absent)
123456 10000 some value
123457 20000 some value
123458 30000 some value
```

content of 20161202.csv

```
key value more columns (this line (header) is absent)
123456 10000 some value
123457 80000 some value
123458 30000 some value
```

content of 20161203.csv

```
key value more columns (this line (header) is absent)
123456 50000 some value
123457 70000 some value
123458 30000 some value
```

I want to compare a file with date 'D' to the file with date 'D+1', based on value column. Then I am interested in those two consecutive files which have maximum number of rows different. So like here if I compare 20161201.csv with 20161202.csv, I get only 2nd row mismatching

`(123457 20000 some value and 123457 80000 some value, mismatched because of 20000 != 80000)`

then  if I compare 20161202.csv with 20161203.csv, I get 2 rows mismatching(1st and 2nd rows)

Hence, 20161202.csv and 20161203.csv are my target files here.

I am looking for a sequence of bash commands which can do the same.

**PS: Number of rows in a file are huge(around 3000) and you can assume that all files have same year and month(number of files<30).**

Comment: is not clear what is the requested output. You need the output per compared pair, or a big grand output with the mismatched = unique lines of all lets say 30 files (one per day)?

Comment: Also, the code you look for, should check if the two compared files have 1 day difference or this is granted by default?

Comment: I want a pair which is corresponding to maximum difference. My output would be a single pair corresponding to maximum difference.

Comment: OK. About filenames? Should be checked or we can assume that we have let's say 30 consecutive files so no filename checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without checking if the filenames respect the date comparison rule (data file vs date+1 file), you could do something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' fn;do files+=("$fn");done < <(find . -name '201612*.csv' -print0) 
#Load all filenames in an array. Using null separation we ensure that filenames will be  
#handled correctly no matter if they do contain spaces or other special chars.

max=0
for ((i=0;i<"${#files[@]}"-1;i++));do #iterate through the filenames array
  a="${files[i]}";b="${files[i+1]}" #compare file1 with file2, file2 with file3, etc - in series
  differences=$(grep -v -Fw -f <(cut -d' ' -f2 "$a") <(cut -d' ' -f2 "$b") |wc -l)
  echo "comparing $a vs $b - non matching lines=$differences" #Just for testing - can be removed .
  [[ "$max" -lt "$differences" ]] && max="$differences" && ahold="$a" && bhold="$b" #When we have the max differences we keep the names of the files
done

echo "max differences found=$max between $ahold and $bhold" #reporting max differences and in which files found
```

The core of getting non matching lines between two files is grep.
You can try manually the grep to see that the results are correct:

```
grep -v -F -w -f <(cut -d' ' -f2 file1) <(cut -d' ' -f2 file2)
```

grep options:
-v : returns non matched lines (reverse operation of grep)
-F : fixed -not regex - match
-w : word match to avoid 5000 to match with 50000
-f : load patterns from file, in particular from file1, field2.With this pattern we will grep/search field2 of file2.
wc -l : counts the matches = non matched lines
<(cut -d' ' -f2 file2) : We grep the field2 of file2 and not the whole file2 to avoid possible matches of file1/field2 in other columns of file2 than column2

### Alternative Solution with awk

Instead of grep , you can use an awk like this:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}!($2 in a)' file1 file2
```

This will print the same results as of `grep -v`

file1/field2($2) will be loaded in an array `a`
lines of file2/field2 ($2) that are not in this array (non matching fields) will be printed.

Can be also piped to `|wc -l` to count the non-matching lines , as in grep.

So if you prefer to use awk, this line :

```
differences=$(grep -v -Fw -f <(cut -d' ' -f2 "$a") <(cut -d' ' -f2 "$b") |wc -l)
```

must be changed to:

```
differences=$(awk 'NR==FNR{a[$2];next}!($2 in a)' $a $b |wc -l)
```

In any case, it seems that you need an array to hold the filenames and then you need a loop to iterate through the files and compare them in pairs.

Comment: @HrishikeshGoyal Answer explained,and updated also with awk solution

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was a kind of chalenge to implement.

With bellow code , based purely on awk (gnu awk actually), all we need is a starting point / a starting file1. Then awk automatically will get the next file2 (by adding 1 day) and compare those two files for different lines.

If there are missing files from the chain , then script readjust file names of files1 and 2 to check for different lines in adjacent files by respecting the rule of +1 day.

You should normally be able to run the script even with copy paste (works in my bash even with comments included) or you can save the code in a separate file (i.e test.awk) that will be loaded by awk with the -f switch (awk -f test.awk).

```
awk -v file1="20161201.csv" \
'function incfile(file,days)                                        #function receives two arguments: file and days
    {
    match(file,/(....)(..)(..)/,fn);                                #splits the string of file to format fn[1]=YYYY,fn[2]=MM and fn[3]=DD
    newfile=sprintf("%s%s%02d%s",fn[1],fn[2],fn[3]+days,".csv");    #this function increase the filename by days variable
    return (newfile)                                                #i.e file 20161201.csv returns 20161201+days
    };
BEGIN \
{
    chkdays=1; 
    while (chkdays<=15)
    {
        {
        file2=incfile(file1,1);                                     #Built filename of file2 by increasing file1 +1 day
        if (getline < file2 < 0)                                    #Check if file2 exists
            {
            print file1,"vs",file2,"skipped:",file2 "  not found";  #Print a help message - can be removed
            chkdays=chkdays+2;                                      #increase days counter for the while loop by 2
            file1=incfile(file1,2);                                 #Increase filename of file1 by 2 days (20161201 will be 20161203)
            file2=incfile(file2,2);                                 #The same for filename of file2 (20161202 will be 20161204)
            }
        else                                                        #if file2 exists
            {
            close(file2);                                           
            print "comparing",file1,"vs",file2; 
            while (getline var <file1)                              #read from file1 a line and assign it to var
                {split(var,ff1,OFS);a[ff1[2]]};                     #split line from file 2 (var) to fields, and keep the field2 in an array as index
            while (getline var2 <file2)
                {
                split(var2,ff2,OFS);                                #same for file2.split the line read (var2) 
                if (!(ff2[2] in a)) {print ">",var2;l=l+1};         #check if ff2[2] (file2-field2) is not found on the array created by file1-field2
                }
            if (l>maxd) {maxd=l;maxp=file1 " vs " file2};           #hold/save max different lines found and hold also the files that maxd was found
            file1=file2;                                            #Assign file2 to be file1 in order to repeat the loop
            chkdays=chkdays+1;                                      #Increase check days counter by 1
            delete a;l=0;close(file1);close(file2)                  #unset all necessary vars and close files
            }
        }
    };                                                              #End of BEGIN section
    print "max different lines=",maxd,"found at pair:",maxp         #Print the results
}'                                                                  #Finished
```

Output:

```
comparing 20161201.csv vs 20161202.csv
> 123457 80000 some value
comparing 20161202.csv vs 20161203.csv
> 123456 50000 some value
> 123457 70000 some value
20161203.csv vs 20161204.csv skipped: 20161204.csv  not found
20161205.csv vs 20161206.csv skipped: 20161206.csv  not found
20161207.csv vs 20161208.csv skipped: 20161208.csv  not found
20161209.csv vs 20161210.csv skipped: 20161210.csv  not found
comparing 20161211.csv vs 20161212.csv
> 123457 80000 some value
> 123458 15000 some value
> 123458 16000 some value
> 123458 17000 some value
comparing 20161212.csv vs 20161213.csv
> 123456 50000 some value
> 123457 70000 some value
> 123458 20000 some value
> 123458 25000 some value
> 123458 35000 some value
20161213.csv vs 20161214.csv skipped: 20161214.csv  not found
comparing 20161215.csv vs 20161216.csv
max different lines= 5 found at pair: 20161212.csv vs 20161213.csv

$ cat 20161212.csv
123456 10000 some value
123457 80000 some value
123458 30000 some value
123458 15000 some value
123458 16000 some value
123458 17000 some value

$ cat 20161213.csv
123456 50000 some value
123457 70000 some value
123458 20000 some value
123458 15000 some value
123458 25000 some value
123458 35000 some value

# csv files 01,02,03 are copy paste from your OP. file 11 is a copy of file 01.
```

PS: You can remove all the print parts of awk and keep only the last summarize command.

Hope this code to be helpfull and well working.